# Weird graphical artifacts after closing context menu

Tags: display, graphics

So I've just installed elementaryOS Juno again, updated everything, installed all my programs, when I noticed a weird bug, that occurs all the time.

When closing the right-click context menu, or a drop-down menu (e.g. in LibreOffice) the shadow of the menu remains on screen, which is not too bad, but annoys me.

[image]

Look at the desktop next to the window.

The interesting part: When I recorded the screenshot there was also an artifact where the right-click menu can be seen, so I am guessing, that it has something to do with elementaryOS still thinking that the menu is active, therefore still drawing the shadow?

I have searched for the problem, but only found one person with the same problem online, but no solution.

Maybe anyone here can help me to optimize my experience.

EDIT: Here is the related issue https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/605

Comment: Having the same issue here. Please report this bug to the developers: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues

Comment: Please don't forget to update the question with issue link.

Comment: I also get this weird shadows on Odin when using Firefox. My graphics are through a 2080Ti. Current gala version is 6.2.